# Show directions on Kakao maps, start/destination encoded in url

Tags: directions

I have manged to encode **destination**: https://map.kakao.com/link/to/37.402056,127.108212

But I have not succeeded to also add **start** location for directions on Kakao maps? I need both start and destination encoded in url so that directions are drown on page after click on url.

Answer (score 2):

**Like this?** 
we can get it after select a location.

```
https://map.kakao.com/
?sX=500000              <-- startX[ Wcongnamul coordinates.]
&sY=1084098             <-- startY[ Wcongnamul coordinates.]
&sName=startName        <-- depend on you

&eX=523953              <-- startX[ Wcongnamul coordinates.]
&eY=1084098             <-- startY[ Wcongnamul coordinates.]
&eName=destinationName  <-- depend on you
```

Full URL

```
https://map.kakao.com/?sX=500000&sY=1084098&sName=startName&eX=523953&eY=1084098&eName=destinationName
```

**X** and **Y** it mean... `Wcongnamul coordinates`.

Can be get it easily by **Kakao Map API**

**How to get LatLng by Coords**

[image: test]
[image: toLatLng]

> **[ToLatLng()](http://apis.map.kakao.com/web/documentation/#Coords_toLatLng)**
>   Returns the coordinates of the object in WGS84 coordinates.

**How to get Coord by LatLng**
[image]
[image]

> **[ToCoords()](http://apis.map.kakao.com/web/documentation/#LatLng_toCoords)**
>   Returns the coordinates of the object in Wcongnamul coordinates.

Comment: If you find out what x and y are, or just conversion formula from wgs84 to this, you will get the points. I have already seen these type of links but idk what coordinate format is this.

Comment: this is `Wcongnamul coordinates `

Comment: refer from... http://apis.map.kakao.com/web/documentation/#LatLng_toCoords

Comment: @watbywbarif we have updated what you want you can use **Duam Open API** to convert too but im not sure in function

Comment: I have not verified it yet, but I have to award bounty soon so I will believe you and check it out later.

Comment: @I'mLimit sorry, I now see that it was you who made all the updates. Kind of  sorry that you didn't collect the bounty.

Comment: Nevermind @siusiulala was find out this answer better than me

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunely because [this](http://apis.map.kakao.com/web/guide/#routeurl)

> **Get directions(web)**
>
> You can use the coordinates or place ID to create a directions URL that specifies that location as your destination.
>
> URL Pattern Example
>
> / link / to / name, latitude, longitude
>
> https://map.kakao.com/link/to/KakaoPangyo+Office,37.402056,127.108212
>
> / link / to / place ID
>
> https://map.kakao.com/link/to/18577297

But i found it can do in Android/iOS with this

> **Get Directions (Android/iOs)**
>
> **Android**
>   daummaps://route?sp=37.537229,127.005515&ep=37.4979502,127.0276368&by=CAR
>
> **iOS**
>   kakaomap://route?sp=37.537229,127.005515&ep=37.4979502,127.0276368&by=CAR

Comment: Good finding for iOS and Android, but sadly it is of no use to me. I did try with similar format for https, but no effect.

Comment: me too. so hard to find it